# How to reach to the clicked dropdown list item in order to find its next sibling element in React js?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Sorry if this is a silly question. But I am trying to do it not inside CSS, but by dynamic code. I have a drowdown menu. And under each title I want to toggle its submenu. This is the nav list:

```
   <ul>
    <li>
        <Link onClick={toggleSubMenu}>Nav Item A</Link>
        <ul className='...'>
          <li>
            <Link to="#0">Submenu Item 1</Link>
          </li>

          <li>
            <Link to="#0">Submenu Item 2</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <Link onClick={toggleSubMenu}>Nav Item B</Link>
        <ul className='...'>
          <li>
            <Link to="#0">Submenu Item 1</Link>
          </li>

          <li>
            <Link to="#0">Submenu Item 2</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

And here is the functions:

```
const toggleSubMenu = () => {
    // here what should I write in order to open Nav Item's Submenu
  }
```

I am trying to show/hide each Nav Item's submenu dynamically by onClick attribute of each. I don't know how to add a classname to next sibling, I mean adding the classname "show" to that  which is coming after , I think this way it could be done but I don't know how syntax would be. Or maybe any other way?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "toggle its submenu"?  Where in the code are you trying to show/hide something?  It's not clear to me what exactly you're asking or what isn't working as expected in the code shown.

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Can you provide more info?
Where is the dropdown menu?

Why the first link's action says `openSubMenu` and the next one `closeSubMenu`?

Comment: @David Sorry for not being neat. Now I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

A simple state atom and callback, and then you just don't render the submenu if it's not open.

```
function Menu() {
  const [submenuOpen, setSubmenuOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const toggleSubMenu = React.useCallback(() => setSubmenuOpen((f) => !f), []);
  return (
    <li>
      <Link onClick={toggleSubMenu}>Nav Item</Link>
      {submenuOpen ? (
        <ul className="...">
          <li>
            <Link to="#0">Submenu Item 1</Link>
          </li>

          <li>
            <Link to="#0">Submenu Item 2</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      ) : null}
    </li>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer is right, but it will open all submenus of all Nav Items. I edited the question due to your answer. I will accept it if you can edit your answer due to that each Nav Item will open its own submenu. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Give each menu their own component then.

Comment: but this will decrease loading time and performance

Comment: Not in any measurable way in this scale.